# SQL Server 2008 non-clustered index

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 with 3 non-clustered indexes. This table gets populated at the end of each month when the month end process is done. During month end process thousands of rows are inserted in this table. Due to the indexes it takes a lot of time to complete the month end process.

So what should I do now? Do I delete the indexes before month end process and recreate them at the end of month end process? Or is there any way to temporarily inactive the indexes before month end and re active the indexes at the end of month end?

Comment: "Due to the indexes it takes a lot of time to complete the Month End process." - how have you determined that?

Comment: @Mitch when there where no Indexes it took less then a minute to run the Month End Process SP. but after i created the indexes to it takes couple of minutes.

Comment: @Mitch my question is: is there any way to inactive the indexes at the beginning of the Month End Process and reactive the indexes at the end of the Month End Process?

Comment: @Mitch Thanks i got what i need after doing some searching.

Comment: Load by the order of the clustered index if you can.   Don't forget to defrag the clustured index.

Comment: You're only talking about non-clustered indexes - do you also have a **clustered** index on that table? Contrary to popular belief, having a **good clustered index** can actually speed up operations - even inserts! See [Kimberly Tripp: The Clustered Index Debate Continues...](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-clustered-index-debate-continues/) for explanations. Having heap tables (without clustered index) is typically a really really bad idea.

Comment: @marc_s: no i don't have any clustered index. thanks for the suggestion and the link i will keep it in my mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You can script out the relevant non-clustered indexes and then drop them, perform the load and then recreate them

OR

1. Disable the relevant non-clustered indexes, perform the load and then recreate them with  `ALTER INDEX REBUILD` statements

   - [ALTER INDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
   - [Disabling Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177406%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx)
   - [How to: Rebuild an Index (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187874%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)